# What is this new room in the tavern?

Tags: dungeon-defender-eternity

While the tavern in Eternity is very familiar, there is one room that is new.

[image: New Room]

What is this place?  Is there anything special to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Hall of Heroes. It was originally going to be a special room used in connection with Dungeon Defenders 2, however that idea was scrapped when development for Dungeon Defenders Eternity was halted. Instead, players were rewarded with a modest amount of DD2 gems for owning Dungeon Defenders or Dungeon Defenders Eternity.

As of right now, that room serves no purpose and is completely superfluous to the game.